# Proper usage of metrics with Kivy(So GUI scales well across devices)

Tags: android, python, scale, kivy, screen-density

I am trying to get my game to look/scale well across different devices. I am attempting to introduce the `dp` and `sp` metrics into my apps as much as possible, but in this case I am refactoring a game to use these metrics for layout and widget sizing.

Where before, my layouts were sized using `size_hint` in order to have everything get it's size relative to it's parent(the app itself is not given a size, nor is the window, but the root widget/layout has `size_hint=(1, 1)`), I am now faced with replacing this system with `dp` values, and can't figure out what they should be.

I am thinking, that if I just size the *root widget*, *App* itself, or *Window* with `dp`, then I could continue to use `size_hint`ing, as this would have a trickle down effect and scale everything correctly from the top on down, so to speak. And for this, It seemed like getting the resolution or density of a devices screen would be a great help(so I could use it to size my root widget/App/Window, per device). Is that possible with Kivy? Will this work? Is there a better way? What would you do? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using size_hint alone already guarantees a degree of scale independence, as (as you note) all the sizes will be relative.

Kivy internally checks some resolution related values of the device, and this is basically the point of dp; something like `dp(10)` for instance should be the same *actual* size on any device, in terms of real size on the screen in e.g. centimetres. This won't actually be quite right, if nothing else I think devices don't report precisely right results, but unless this is very important it will already take care of making things mostly look the same anywhere.

I'm not sure what you mean about setting the App size - in Android's window manager an App just fills the screen (at least in most cases).

Comment: This gives me more hope that dp and size_hint could solve my issue. However, I notice that when messing around with 'python main.py -m screen:etc.' that screens like nexus7.2 and nexus7 make my game look overly wide(over stretched), and the game seems less playable. This is what started me wondering about how to detect the screen size/dpi/density. If I could detect a screen over a certian size, perhaps I could make relevant changes to the width(for instance) of the screen.