# Why Kivy app is scaled down in Android but not in development

Tags: python, android, kivy

I've got this code which works like a charm on my Linux machine  (imports omitted):

```
class Background(Widget):

    def __init__(self, source):
        super(Background, self).__init__()
        self.image = Sprite(source=source)
        self.add_widget(self.image)
        self.size = self.image.size
        self.image_copy = Sprite(source=source, x=self.width)
        self.add_widget(self.image_copy)


class Sprite(Image):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Sprite, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size = self.texture_size

class Game(Widget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Game, self).__init__()
        self.background = Background(
            source='assets/images/bg.jpg')
        self.size = self.background.size


class TrackerWarsApp(App):

    def build(self):
        game = Game()
        Window.size = game.size
        return game
```

This gives me background nicely stretched on the laptop but when I try the game in Android phone background picture is shrunk.

How can I troubleshoot this ?

**Suggested edit:**

```
class Background(Widget):

    def __init__(self, source):
        super(Background, self).__init__()
        self.image = Sprite(source=source)
        self.image.allow_stretch = True   #  <==
        self.add_widget(self.image)
        self.size = self.image.size
        self.image_copy = Sprite(source=source, x=self.width)
        self.add_widget(self.image_copy)
```

**another edit:**

```
class Background(Widget):

    def __init__(self, source):
        super(Background, self).__init__()
        self.image = Sprite(
            source=source, allow_stretch=True)
        self.add_widget(self.image)
        self.size = self.image.size
        self.image_copy = Sprite(
            source=source, allow_stretch=True, x=self.width)
        self.add_widget(self.image_copy)


class Sprite(Image):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Sprite, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size = self.texture_size
        x, y = dp(self.size[0]), dp(self.size[1])
        self.size = (x, y)
        self.size_hint = (None, None)

class Game(Widget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Game, self).__init__()
        self.background = Background(
            source='assets/images/bg.jpg')
        self.size = self.background.size
        self.add_widget(self.background)

class TrackerWarsApp(App):

    def build(self):
        game = Game()
        Window.size = game.size
        self.icon = 'assets/images/logo.png'
        return game
```

Here I'm trying to convert all sprites size (including the background picture) into pixel-independent values. I'm getting overstretched background.

Comment: Set the `allow_stretch` property of the Image to `True`.

Comment: @inclement No effect.

Comment: The whole game is scaled down for some reason.

Comment: Can you post a minimal runnable example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Well, the simplest way to demo it would be to grab the code and try it on your spare Android phone. Here's the repo:  https://gitlab.com/godsengineer/trackerwars

Comment: No, your error is undoubtedly not to do with most of the code there, so there's no point spending time pulling out the irrelevant bits - that's what you need to do.

Comment: But, it sounds like you may be declaring all your sizes in pixels. Is the size difference on the phone just due to the different dpi?

Comment: It could be. I didn't consider different dpi when making the game. Could you drop here a link where I can learn what I need to edit my code ?

Comment: Use kivy.metrics.dp to convert to density-independent pixel values. This is only approximate, but it's the best you can do easily. Other than that, you have to decide how you want the app to change on different device types, and go from there (e.g. you could make everything relative to the screen size, so it's identical on all phones)

Comment: So I added the new import and added `dp([size])` to all lines where I'm doing something with sizes and positions. The game turned out to be completely messed up on the phone. Didn't even render correctly. I'm reverting changes as it was better before. The game was just scaled down but was rendered well. Thank you for trying to help me.

Comment: I found this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037748/proper-usage-of-metrics-with-kivyso-gui-scales-well-across-devices  looks like correct scaling is a common problem when testing Kivy app on device.

Comment: I tried to include `size_hint = (1,1)` which helps in some cases but no effect on my app.

Comment: It looks like we've identified the problem, everything else is details - you need to understand what's wrong and apply the scaling the way you want it. Make a simple example to test with, then make it steadily more complicated (e.g. add more of your app back in) and check that it continues to work as you want at each stage.

Comment: And if you have problems with a simpler example, feel free to ask about those here.

Comment: @inclement  Yeah ... I'm gonna take this approach. I really want to understand it and get down how it works.

Comment: @inclement  Can you please take a look at latest edit ? I stripped the code off everything except from code where I'm adding background picture. I'm getting either background that is shrunk or overstretched. It's sad that there isn't an algorithm that would make sure the pixels are adjusted depending on size of the screen automatically.

Comment: @inclement  What do you think may help to achieve background image to fill up the screen ? As you can see I used the class attribute `allow_stretch=True` and I used the `dp` function in a way that made sense to me.